# Creating a buy stop with stop loss order on Think Or Swim

Tags: thinkorswim

Using Think Or Swim, is there a way to create a Buy Order for a stock with a stop and simultaneously create a sell order with a stop loss that only gets triggered if the stock is purchased?  I'm trying to do so with using Buy Custom-->Stop but I keep getting an error that I can't borrow the stock.

Comment: Conventional trade orders don't allow you to set up conditional instructions for a position that you don't already have.  IOW, you can set trigger and limit  conditions for buying the stock but you can't set the conditions for selling it because you haven't purchased it yet.  I suspect that the stock in question is non borrowable so whatever order you are currently trying to place is being interpreted as an opening short sell position.

Comment: @BobBaerker Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

First create your buy stop order for the opening trade:

[image]

Then change the Advanced Order dropdown to "1st trgs Seq":

[image]

Then right-click on the buy stop order and select "Create opposite order":

[image]

Then set your stop price for the closing trade:

[image]

Then click "Confirm and Send" and you will see the following under your working orders:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- "Order Entry Tools" (bottom tab of Trade interface)
- Order Entry
- Choose "1st trgs All" (or sequence, etc.) https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/howToTos/thinkManual/Trade/Order-Entry-Tools/Order-Types.html

As you'll probably discover, some of these order types don't work for EXT.

- Like accepted answer said, "Create Opposite Order(s)".
- Confirm and Send -> Save

This opens a dialog box. You should see a "Save" option, which hopefully saves us some time.

- Switch to "Saved Orders" tab. Right click on your beautiful creation. Choose "Create Duplicate Advanced Order"
- Back to "Order Entry" -- now you know how to reuse your saved order. And your order is saved for all accounts.
- Click "Confirm and Send" again, review everything, then send it.
- Assuming you set limits, click back to "Active Trader" and check "auto send" and then you can drag/drop to adjust your limits.

Of course, do this at your own risk. If I missed something, edit my answer.

Thoughts:

1. Hypothetically, ToS could simulate all the advanced order types in extended hours, either via some queue in their backend (faster) or in the user client itself (slower.) Of course with some kind of warning like "Only the 1st order reaches the exchange, but we will submit the sequence on your behalf, as needed, etc."
2. The "Template" in Active Trader is different from the "Saved Orders" which is confused further by "shared orders."